# Showing and Popping Multiple View Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

So here's my problem.

First `ViewController` has some fields regarding name, date, no. of people of an Event (the user creates and event). It also has a button that will transition the user to a new `viewController` with a `mapView` where user will create a Pin. After user creates a Pin, user can press the pin (or do some other action that confirms that the Pin user put on the map is correct) and user will be transitioned to a new `tableViewController` with multiple locations near the Pin he selected (using Foursquare API).

Then the user must be transitioned to the first `ViewController`. The Location user tapped must be sent to the first `ViewController`.

This is my first time working with multiple `ViewControllers` and I need your help.

How would I do this (don't miss on any details please :D) ?

Comment: Use an [unwind segue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html) in order to access variables from a previous view controller.

Comment: Can I unwind from the **thirdViewController** to the **firstViewController** ? Should I embed them in a Navigation Controller ?

Comment: Yes to both. Check out [this site](http://ashishkakkad.com/2015/04/work-with-unwind-segue-in-swift-language-ios-8/) for an example/tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an unwind segue to pass data backwards through view controllers embedded in a navigation controller.

Here's a brief example.

In your first view controller you can have something like:

```
var text: String?

@IBAction func unwindSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let viewController = segue.sourceViewController as? ViewController2 {
        text = viewController.textField.text
    }
    print(text!)
}
```

Add the unwind segue in the second view controller on the storyboard by ctrl-dragging from the view controller (yellow circle with a square in, to the exit icon (either at the top of the view controller or in the document outline) and click on the unwind segue that you created to create a manual segue. Then in the document outline set the unwind segue's identifier so that you can refer to it (I've called it simply "Unwind" for this example).

In the second view controller (the one you want to pass back from) add this:

```
@IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

@IBAction func backButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Unwind", sender: nil)
}
```

This simple example will let you pass back the text from the `textField` in your second view controller.

n.b. You can unwind more than one view at a time.